# Use UIViewController vs separate datasource object to manage model objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm writing a simple iOS app that uses a table view to display information from a set of model objects (each is an instance of "NTTrip"). I'm deciding between using a single subclass of UITableViewController to manage both the view and the set of model objects or whether I should separate the logic of managing the model objects into a new object that would act as a data source to the table view (i.e., sort of split up the logic into a "view controller" and a "model controller"). Is this a good idea or would I be adding extra complexity into a system that doesn't necessarily need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I like to split specific responsibilities like a UITableView's datasource out into non-UIViewController controllers. I think that that separation makes it easier to test and maintain my controllers.

However that doesn't always make sense. If you're considering using a UITableViewController then that implies that you expect your table view to fill the screen and here are probably not many other behaviors your UIViewController subclass would be responsible for. I think multiple controllers would be unnecessarily complicated if there are not clear independent responsibilities for each controller.

One alternative might be to have a single UIViewController subclass which acts as the table view's delegate and datasource. That controller can call out to some `NTTripService` controller which can be responsible for loading and persisting your `NTTrip` objects and make them available to many UIViewController subclasses for display.

Comment: Great, thanks! Your last idea is exactly along the lines I was thinking. I'm realizing I will need at least a couple of different view controllers to have access to the data, so it probably makes sense to create the Service controller.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are typically the most complex part of your app and are expected to talk with the data and manage the view. In iOS you typically don't have data controllers. As such, your table view controller should also communicate with your model to display the proper data for your table view. By having another data controller talk to the data model and act as a datasource, what else would your original controller do? The other extreme, of course, is to parcel every bit of work into a separate controller…but you see the problem with that.

Bottom line—your single table view controller should manage both your data and your table view—that's what the controller is meant to do.

A wrench though—if your same data is managed (edited, used) by other controllers, you may want to factor that out into a service as Jonah suggests. Otherwise, it's just unnecessary work and complication.